# Convergence in probability for a sequence of discrete uniform random variables to a continuous uniform random varible.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Consider the probability space $\left([0,1],\mathcal{B},m\right)$. Let $X_k$ and $X$ be the random variables defined by

$$
X_k(y)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{j}{k}\mathbb{I}_{\left[\frac{j}{k},\frac{j+1}{k}\right)}(y)\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }X(y)=y. 
$$

**Show that $X_k\rightarrow X$ in probability, where $X\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$**

Here is what I have so far:

Let $\epsilon>0,k\in\mathbb{N}$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left[\left|X_k-X\right|>\epsilon\right]&=\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{y\in [0,1]:\left|X_k(y)-X(y)\right|>\epsilon\right\}\right].
\end{aligned}
$$

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that

$$
\mathbb{P}[X_k=y]=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{k}&\text{ if }y=\frac{j}{k}\text{ for }j=1,\dots,k,\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Thus

$$
X_k\sim\text{Unif}\left\{\frac{1}{k},\frac{2}{k},\dots, \frac{k}{k}\right\}
$$

By **Markov's Inequality** we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|X_k(y^*)-X(y^*)\right|&=\left|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{j}{k}\mathbb{I}_{\left[\frac{j}{k},\frac{j+1}{k}\right)}(y^*)-y^*\right|
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}\left[\left|X_k-X\right|>\epsilon\right]&=\mathbb{P}\left[\left\{y\in [0,1]:\left|X_k(y)-X(y)\right|>\epsilon\right\}\right]\\
&\le \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_k-X\right|^2\right]}{\epsilon^2}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[(X_k-X)^2\right]}{\epsilon^2}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X_k^2\right]-2\mathbb{E}\left[X_kX\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]}{\epsilon^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Not entirely sure of how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

You are making it way too complicated. For any $y$ there is a unique $j$ such that $y \in [\frac j k,\frac {j+1}k)$. For this $j$ we have $X_k(y)=\frac j k$. Hence, $|X_k(y)-X(y)|=|X_k(y)-y|<\frac 1 k$. [Any two points of the interval $[\frac j k,\frac {j+1}k)$ are at distance not exceeding $\frac  1 k$]. It follows that $X_k(y) \to X_y$ for every $y$. And pointwise convergence implies convergence in probability. Actually, in this case,  $P(|X_k-X|>\epsilon)=0$ whenever $k>\frac 1 {\epsilon}$.